# Next.js website works under IP address, but not under domain

Tags: url, deployment, continuous-integration, hosting

So I am really desperate right now. It is new year's eve and I don't want to deal with this stuff anymore, but I don't want to slide into 2023 with a broken web app.

Yesterday, suddenly out of nowhere my Next.js production website stopped working properly. The project works well on my localhost, no issues. Also it works fine on my server (if I access the website via IP_ADRESS:3000). But when I use the production URL, the website opens and looks fine but I cannot interact with it, nothing is clickable, nothing reacts, the links do not work, the inputs are broken.

I'm hosting it on a Ubuntu & Nginx DigitalOcean droplet, with Node & Next.js - also I use Cloudflare (and I think it has something to do with that, since with the bare IP address the website works fine).

I tried a lot of things, put it onto a new server, reinstalled Nginx, reinstalled the SSL certificate, rebuild the production build etc, but it still does not work, when I access it through the website url, so the issue must be with that. Though I am really frustrated right now and I don't know what might be causing this.

Comment: I have the same problem, do you already have the solution?